# How should I avoid 404 errors when scraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm accessing web pages by looping over a couple of variables to insert into the URL

There will be occasional 404 errors.

How do I insert some sort of catch for these pages to avoid breaking the code. I currently use the XML package but of course could load others if appropriate

TIA

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404278/using-readhtmltable-from-xml-package-to-scrape-site-uncertain-error-message)

Comment: @Justin. Tx I used that as basis. Did you want to make it an answer

Answer (score 0):

Most of times I use `RCurl::url.exists()`. In case you have a list or a data frame containing all the urls you can try this:

```
map(p, ~ifelse(RCurl::url.exists(.), ., NA))
```

HTH!